# Understand the window method

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I am learning rxjs and struggle to understand the `window` method. I read the [doc](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-window) a lot of times and I miss the aha effect.

Could someone explain me on a very simple example, how can I use the `window` method and in which situation can I use it.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation could be more clear here : http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/window.html.

In short, the window-family operators take a source stream, and emits a series of output observables. Source stream's values are grouped according to some criteria (usually time), and all values respecting the same criteria are emitted in the same observable. So it is basically a way to group/partition a source stream values according to some criteria, with each group/partition being enclosed into its corresponding output observable.

Talking specifically about the `window` operator, a group is whatever values are between two emissions of an observable (the `windowBoundaries` parameter).

A typical use of `window` is to group a source stream's values in chunks of similar size (i.e. buffering and emitting when the buffer is full or when a given time has passed). You have a simple example in the doc link you have provided.

Hopefully that is a little bit more clear,

Comment: It is like a window of for example time, that I can do something? The simple example, that the doc provide, when the click event emits, only clicks within 1 second will be pushed right?